# Is it possible to use Excel Worksheet Functions in ExcelScript?

Tags: excel, vba, office-scripts

I want to know how a worksheet function can be called in an ExcelScript.
Here it is explained for VBA: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/worksheet-functions-in-macro/

You can get an application-object in ExcelScript, but it seems that none of the functions can be called:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
   let app = workbook.getApplication();
}
```

Comment: You can always put a formula in a field, let it calculate and then get the result. Inefficient but it would work.

Comment: Workbook functions are not currently supported in Office Scripts. They are supported in Office.Js. So they will likely be supported in Office Scripts eventually. You can read more about their usage in Office.Js here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheet-functions